# Javascript external file

Tags: javascript, php, html, calendar

I am trying to get this calendar I found on the net to work with my webpage. The strange thing is that after modifying its external "calendar.js" file, nothing takes effect. I even tested it out by moving the folder holding the calendar files to another location and the program still worked.

Below is my javascript link to the js file:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/Hardship/Calendar/calendar.js"></script>
```

My php code below:

```
echo '<td align="middle"><input type="text" name="date2" id="date2" style=\'font-weight: bold;\' disabled value="" class=\'inputBoxStyle\' disabled  ><img src=\'/Hardship/Calendar/cal.gif\' align=\'absmiddle\' onmouseover="fnInitCalendar(this, \'date2\',\'close=true,top=-300,left=-150\')"></td>';​
```

Can someone please explain why it still works after moving the source file to another location? Note: I did do f5 refresh and restart IE browser as well but that didn't make any difference.

Also, why my changes to the calendar.js file didn't take effect at all?

Comment: Try CTRL + SHIFT + R after making changes to your js file

Comment: Using only f5 can reload resources from cache. I believe ctrl/command+f5 reloads from server for most browsers. One of the best methods is to disable your browsers cache through the developer tools menu. For google chrome, this option would be under the "Network" tab. It's probably something similar for IE.

Comment: @raj454raj, where do I do that? on my ie browser? Please be specific. Thank you.

Comment: Yes this is to refresh the webpage. This removes cached pages(js)

Comment: raj454raj, CTRL + SHIFT + R didn't do anything to the browser. Shashand, I went thru the "advance" tab in IE but didn't see that option. We are not allowed to use chrome at work. Only IE.

Comment: Was it working when stored on a network drive, but not working when stored locally?

Comment: Equalsk, I never tested it on a local drive. This intranet webpage is supposed to be on a network drive.

Comment: If you can't clear the cache through IE itself, can you delete the contents of %TEMP% and %APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

Comment: I did several times "delete browsing history" under IE options but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the js file and it works now. The ctrl-f5 did help too. Thank you all.